# Finding last dictionary with key in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, search, lodash

Given an array of dictionaries, how do I find the last dictionary that contains a certain key, "test".

I've found the first using:
`answerDict = myarray.find(hasOwnProperty('test'));`

But I'm not sure how to do that find from right to left.

I've tried using lodash:
`answerDictLast = _.findLast(myarray, function(n){return n.hasOwnProperty('test');});`

but that doesn't work. (I'm getting '_.findLast is not a function' when I run it in node, even after requiring lodash).

I've also looked into using `lastIndexOf` but can't seem to get that to find the key inside the dictionary. Any thoughts? thanks!
I know I could iterate through the entire array, but I'd love to find a neater way to do this, as I suspect there is one.

Comment: If the array isn't really big you could get away with something like `myarray.slice().reverse().find(...`. Or you could simply loop through the array. There are a number of ways to do this to be honest - including using `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the snippet - [`_.findLast()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findLast) is what you need:

```js
const myarray =  [{ v: 1 }, { test: 1 }, { v: 1 }, { test: 2 }, { v: 1 }];

const answerDict = _.findLast(myarray, (v) => _.has(v, 'test'));

console.log(answerDict);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However, [`_.findLast()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findLast) is available from lodash version 2.0.0.
Check your lodash's version.

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate backwards through the array.

```js
var arr = [{ key2 : "sup"}, { key2 : "pick me!"}, {key1 : "not it"}]


function findLastWithKey(array, key){
    for(var i = array.length-1; i>=0 ; i--){
        // put whatever criteria you want here
        if(array[i][key])
          return array[i];
    }
}

console.log(findLastWithKey(arr, "key2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean?

```
var array = ["Apple test", "test Banana", "Peach", "Pumpkin test", "Tomatestto", "Mantestgo", "Guava"],
    arrayContainsCharacterDefine = [];
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i].slice(-4) === 'test'){
           arrayContainsCharacterDefine.push(array[i]);
         }
    }
   console.log(arrayContainsCharacterDefine);// result ["Apple test", "Pumpkin test"];
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tiepnvbn/kay62xx9/)